# CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH package not found

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, colcon, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I've been stuck on an issue in my ROS project after I started using an overlay. I used to just place all of my packages inside /src/ros2/<my_package> . I am trying to move my project into an overlay to make it more modular.

I have reduced my problem to just two packages. Package 1 is named "qualified_msgs" and builds with no issues. My second package is "ros_can_bridge" and this **depends** on the "qualified_msgs" package. My build process is as follows:

1. Build qualified_msgs
2. source /install/local_setup.bash (this should place the qualified_msgs cmake files in the path)
3. Build ros_can_bridge

When I try to execute step I get the following error:

```
 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findqualified_msgs.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this
  project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "qualified_msgs", but CMake did not find one.

 Could not find a package configuration file provided by "qualified_msgs"
  with any of the following names:

   qualified_msgsConfig.cmake
   qualified_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "qualified_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "qualified_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
 "qualified_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
 has been installed.

 ---
Failed   <<< ros_can_bridge [ Exited with code 1 ]
```

However, If I view my build log I can see that this **is** in the path:

Portion of Log:

> Invoking command in '/home/ros/overlay/build/ros_can_bridge': /usr/bin/cmake /home/ros/overlay/ros_can_bridge -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/usr/ros2_ws/aarch64_toolchainfile.cmake -DTHIRDPARTY=ON -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE:BOOL=ON -DCOMPILE_EXAMPLES=OFF -DCMAKE_C_STANDARD=99 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DBUILD_TESTING:BOOL=OFF -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=**/home/ros/overlay/install/qualified_msgs;**/usr/ros2_ws/install/common_interfaces;/usr/ros2_ws/install/visualization_msgs;/usr/ros2_ws/install/ament_lint_common;/usr/ros2_ws/install/ament_cmake_uncrustify;/usr/ros2_ws/install/ament_uncrustify;/usr/ros2_ws/install/uncrustify_vendor;/usr/ros2_ws/install/trajectory_msgs;

I can see that my CMAKE files are indeed in this directory:

Folder Structure[image: image description]

**package.xml for ros_can_bridge:**

> ros_can_bridge
>  0.0.2
>
>   
>  
>  JB
>
> <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>
>
> <build_depend>builtin_interfaces</build_depend>
> <build_depend>rosidl_default_generators</build_depend>
> <build_depend>rclcpp</build_depend>
> <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
> <build_depend>message_runtime</build_depend>
> <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
> <build_depend>qualified_msgs</build_depend>
>
> <exec_depend>builtin_interfaces</exec_depend>
> <exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>
> <exec_depend>message_runtime</exec_depend>
> <exec_depend>qualified_msgs</exec_depend>

> <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

> <member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>

> ament_cmake

**Build Command:**

> colcon build 
> --packages-select ros_can_bridge
> --cmake-force-configure 
> --cmake-args 
> " -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/usr/ros2_ws/aarch64_toolchainfile.cmake" 
> " -DTHIRDPARTY=ON" 
> " -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON" 
> " -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF" 
> " -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE:BOOL=ON" 
> " -DCOMPILE_EXAMPLES=OFF" 
> " -DCMAKE_C_STANDARD=99" 
> " -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug" 
> " -DBUILD_TESTING:BOOL=OFF"

Any advice on this would be appreciated, I'm pretty stuck!

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304974/cmake_prefix_path-package-not-found/) by [borgman_jeremy](https://answers.ros.org/users/37924/borgman_jeremy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2018-10-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2018-10-05**:
Can you post the build commands used? My guess is that the dependency may be missing from the `package.xml`. There should be a line in `ros_can_bridge/package.xml` that looks like `<depend>qualified_msgs</depend>`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-06**:
You tagged this `melodic`, but your question is about ROS 2. Melodic is not a ROS 2 release.

Can I ask you to please fix the tagging?

Also: please attach your screenshot to this question directly. I've given you enough karma for that.

You could also consider using `tree`.

**Comment by [borgman_jeremy](https://answers.ros.org/users/37924/borgman_jeremy/) on 2018-10-06**:
@jacobperron, Added the details of package.xml and clarifed the build command. Thanks for the help

@ gvdhoorn. Sorry about that, fixed the post

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-10-08**:
The problem might be in a part you haven't shared yet. Maybe you can share a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) reproducing the problem.

**Comment by [borgman_jeremy](https://answers.ros.org/users/37924/borgman_jeremy/) on 2018-10-09**:
@Dirk   Thanks, as I was trying to reproduce the issue with the simplest example possible I found the problem. This build is in a crosscompiled environment and inside my toolchain file I had the line: set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/install). This was overriding other CMAKe paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The root cause of this issue was related to my  `aarch64_toolchainfile.cmake`  file. This file had the line below:

```
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/install)
```

This was overriding my other paths. Removing this line resolved the issue.

---

Originally posted by [borgman_jeremy](https://answers.ros.org/users/37924/borgman_jeremy/) with karma: 56 on 2018-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-10**:
And a again a win for the MWE / SSCCE.